# failing pull dependencies cloudstack 4 with maven3

Tags: linux, maven-3, apache-cloudstack

```
mvn -P deps                                                    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.cloudstack:cloudstack:4.0.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT (/usr/local/apache-cloudstack-4.0.1-incubating-src/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:11 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 23, column 11: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Maven instructions for major releases after CloudStack 4.0.0-incubating](http://cloudstack.apache.org/develop/environment.html#maven):

To compile Apache CloudStack, go to the cloudstack source folder and run:

`mvn -P developer clean install`

To deploy Apache CloudStack, run:

`mvn -P developer -pl developer,tools/devcloud -Ddeploydb`

Deploy the database next:

`mvn -P developer -pl tools/devcloud -Ddeploysvr`